# How to Display output in Powershell GUI ListViewbox as a table format?

Tags: powershell

I have tried a below code to display output in the ListViewbox. But i can't display any output in the box.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Form"
$Form.TopMost = $true
$Form.Width = 696
$Form.Height = 323

$button2 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.Button
$button2.Text = "Go"
$button2.Width = 60
$button2.Height = 30
$button2.Add_Click({
      $listView3.Text = Get-Process | Out-String
})
$button2.location = new-object system.drawing.point(238,70)
$button2.Font = "Microsoft Sans Serif,10"
$Form.controls.Add($button2)

$listView3 = New-Object system.windows.Forms.ListView
$listView3.Text = "listView"
$listView3.Width = 330
$listView3.Height = 600
$listView3.location = new-object system.drawing.point(269,146)
$Form.controls.Add($listView3)

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
$Form.Dispose()
```

I need to display the output in the table format in the listbox as well.. Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

The `.text` property of a listview control doesn't control what is displayed, you need to add items. Assuming you want to display the process name in the list, instead of:

```
$listView3.Text = Get-Process | Out-String
```

Try:

```
Get-Process | %{$listView3.Items.Add($_.processname)}
```

To add sub items you'll need to do something like this:

```
Get-Process | %{$item = $listView3.Items.Add($_.processname);$item.SubItems.Add($_.Handles)}
```

Comment: Thank u now i able to view the output. Also i need to display the in the format table..

Comment: Try `$listView3.View = "Details"`. You'll probably need to add whichever columns you want to view as sub-items. I'll add an example to my answer.